# Trying to identify unknown connection plug

Tags: connector, wiring, plug

We have a piece of foreign (Turkish) machinery and we are trying to make some adaptions to it in our workshop.  However we need to find out what the below plug is - couple of electrical shops we've been to can't recognise it and we've found nothing similar online as yet.  It looks similar to some internal automobile plugs but I can't exactly match them up with anything.

See the images below so you can see what it looks like.  The 4 hollow connections measure about 5mm in diameter, and about 24mm across all 4 connections.  They extend out from the main plug about 12mm, and the depth of the whole plug is about 26mm.

If anyone can help out with the name/code of the item or where we can source these that would be a great help!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The make and model of the Turkish machine would be a big help, since without it we cannot consider searching for manufacturer documentation/drawings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part shown isn't a million miles for this 3 pin TE connectivity part: -

[image]

It's description on [RS](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-connector-housings/1151727/) is: -

> Universal MATE-N-LOK Series 6.35mm Pitch 3 Way 1 Row Male Straight
>   Crimp Connector Housing

You should be able to get the data sheet and compare dimensions. Then, when happy it matches, locate the female part.

You will probably find that Molex are an alternative supplier - I've seen very similar offerings from them.

Comment: I've found a 4 pin version on RS and Farnell now so that's cool! - Big help many thanks!